# How do validate if user inputs anything other than a character?

Tags: c++, loops, validation, input, char

I have a function that asks if the user wants to return to the main menu.

```
void menuReturn() {
    char cont;
    do {
        cout << "Return to Main Menu? [Y/N]: ";
        cin >> cont;
        cont = toupper(cont);
        if (cont == 'Y') {
            system("cls");
            break;
        }
        else if (cont == 'N') { 
            cout << "Closing program...";
            exit(0);    
        }
        else {
            cout << "Invalid choice" << endl;
        }        
    } while (cont !=  'Y'|| cont != 'N');
}
```

But when the user inputs a string or an integer higher than nine (9), the console shows this:

```
Return to Main Menu? [Y/N]: apple
Invalid choice
Return to Main Menu? [Y/N]: Invalid choice
Return to Main Menu? [Y/N]: Invalid choice
Return to Main Menu? [Y/N]: Invalid choice
Return to Main Menu? [Y/N]: Invalid choice
Return to Main Menu? [Y/N]:
```

How do I get rid of the redundant *return to menu* messages? How do I make it look like this instead?

```
Return to Main Menu? [Y/N]: apple
Invalid choice
Return to Main Menu? [Y/N]:
```

Comment: std::getline will help

Answer (score 0):

Collect the input as a string, then check if it has only one character or not using string.length(), If it is one character convert it to char. You can convert it using strcopy method or just

```
char character = string[0];
```

I'm not sure if the above one works, but try it. Hope it helped!
Also use `std::getline(std::cin, string)` instead of std::cin if you want to input spaces in console!

Answer (score 0):

Whats happening here is that `char` can only hold one character, but `apple` takes up 5 characters.

At each iteration of the loop, `std::cin` reads only 1 character at a time from the console (that you have already entered). Putting the print statement `std::cout << "Read: " << cont;` illustrates this by the below output:

```
Return to Main Menu? [Y/N] apple
Read: a
Return to Main Menu? [Y/N] Read: pInvalid Choice
Return to Main Menu? [Y/N] Read: pInvalid Choice
Return to Main Menu? [Y/N] Read: lInvalid Choice
Return to Main Menu? [Y/N] Read: eInvalid Choice
```

To fix this, either use a `std::string` and `std::getline`, and make sure to validate the entered length is 1.